# Azure Function runs old version of code without receiving trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to build a project in c# using azure durable functions. I have an orchestrator with an http trigger.

Initially I had some mock data for testing, which has been since removed and replaced with real inputs which should be received as part of the triggering http query. When running the project locally, for some reason it is still running the mock data code (apparently completely ignoring the changes made to it, as it even skips all breakpoints in that function). It starts running it without receiving any triggers (logging shows the "reason" is null).

First I only commented out the mock data input code, then I deleted it entirely.

I have tried searching for an explanation but found none.

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project and even deleting it and pulling it back from github. I also tried restarting my computer several times. The issue still persists.

Comment: The local `Azurite storage emulator` must have some old entries of the orchestrator and activity functions, find it and clear it out.

Comment: what version and framework are you using, provide your code and screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

> The local `Azurite storage emulator` must have some old entries of the orchestrator and activity functions, find it and clear it out

As the user @*AnandSowmithiran* suggested, you have to clear the past history data of the Azure Storage Emulator.

Azurite is integrated with the Visual Studio, all these storage emulator data located locally in the Azurite Folder.

Path: `C:\Users\Hari\AppData\Local\Temp\Azurite`

[image]

To clean up the data (old entries), you have to clear all the above visible files and folders from the Azurite local path as mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#workspace-structure) and run/restart the Azurite Storage emulator by following the steps given in same Document.

Also, in the Azure Storage Explorer > Storage Accounts > Local Azurite (Emulator) - delete the folders name starts with `testhubname-{}` and restart the explorer.
[image]